# What is the correct pronoun?

Tags: pronouns

What is the correct pronoun for this sentence "Erica went to get them from the bakery" or is it already correct?

Comment: One would need to know what Erica went to get.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Me
You
Him/Her/It
Us
Them

They are all grammatically valid, but it depends on what Erica went to get.

Comment: Because I downvote answers that are ripoffs of comments, with about no original thought or content added.

Answer (score 0):

In order to verify the correctness of this sentence, we need to know **what** Erica went to get.

---

**Example 1:**

Erica wants a **loaf of bread**, which is sold in the bakery.

The correct pronoun is **it**, as the loaf of bread is a **single** item (singular).

> "We wanted a loaf of bread and Erica went to get it from the bakery"

---

**Example 2:**

Erica wants some **bread rolls**, which are sold in the bakery.

The correct pronoun is **them**, as the rolls are **multiple** items (plural).

> "For the burgers, we needed some bread rolls, and Erica went to get them from the bakery"

---

**Example 3:**

Erica wants to **collect her children**, who are waiting in the bakery.

The correct pronoun is **them**, as she has **multiple** children (plural), and does not change if they are all boys or all girls.

> "Erica's children were waiting in the bakery, and **she** went **there** to **collect** them"

Notes:

- *collect* sounds better than *get* for people
- *there* is used because the bakery has already been referred to
- *she* is used because Erica has already been mentioned

---

**Examples 4 & 5:**

[Using the same structure as example 3]

Erica wants to **collect her boy/girl**, who is waiting in the bakery.

The correct pronoun is either **him** (boy) or **her** (girl), as she has a **single** child (singular)

> "Sarah (Erica's daughter) was waiting in the bakery, and Erica went there to collect her"

or

> "James (Erica's son) was waiting in the bakery, and Erica went there to collect him"
>
> ---

**Example 6 & 7:**

Erica wants to **collect me** or **collect me and some other people**, and I/we am/are waiting in the bakery for her.

The pronouns are either **me** for **I** or **us** for **we**

> "I was waiting in the bakery, and Erica **came** to collect me"

or

> "We were waiting in the bakery, and Erica **came** to collect us"

Notes:

- use of **came** instead of **went there** because it sounds better when saying it from your own point of view - you are there in person

---

**Alternative to examples 4-7**

> "Erica's children were waiting in the bakery for her to [come and] collect them"
>
> "Sarah was waiting in the bakery for Erica to [come and] collect her"
>
> "James was waiting in the bakery for Erica to [come and] collect him"
>
> "I was waiting in the bakery for Erica to [come and] collect me"
>
> "We were waiting in the bakery for Erica to [come and] collect us"

This is probably the best way of saying it, because the referred people **know** that Erica is going to come and collect them and were waiting for her to do that.

---

**Example 8:**

**Very rare**; this would probably be used for someone who had forgotten what had happened.

> "You were [waiting] in the bakery and Erica came to collect you"

Notes:

- the potential omission of 'waiting' because the person was not intending for Erica to come and collect them